# how to filter out non-numeric values

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, reql

I have a table (in a RethinkDB database) that has a bunch of documents with the field `VIN0`. This field almost always stores numbers, as intended.

I had some data corruption recently where there are some strings in place of numbers for the field `VIN0`. Queries I was using to manipulate this data now return the error: `"e: Expected type NUMBER but found STRING in:"`

I'd like to filter for the strings, but I can't seem to find them. Is there a way to use something like `Number.isInteger()` to filter out these items within RethinkDB?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `Number.isNaN('string')`

Comment: leo.fcx: It's ReQL. It's not JavaScript. This doesn't really answer his question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `typeOf` to find type of a field, or a element. Let's say you want to filter document with VIN0 is a number

```
r.db('db').table('table').filter(r.row('VIN0').typeOf().eq('NUMBER'))
```

You can also try to correct problem by using `coereTo` to convert string to number.

```
r.db('db').table('table')
  .filter(r.row('VIN0').typeOf().eq('STRING'))
  .update({VIN0: r.row('VIN0').coerceTo('NUMBER')})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems like the way to go!